# VB.Net: Call a module Method or Routine dynamically with parameters

Tags: vb.net, string, methods, module

I want to run a Method using a **variable name** that is stored in a **Module** with a parameter:

```
Dim subName as String = "sub1"
Dim param as Integer = 123
sub1(param) <- I want to run this using the **subName** string
```

I don't want to use `Select` `Case` because the Methods are in many different modules and I don't want to maintain a select-case function.

I looked up `CallByName` but it seems this only works for Classes. I can't figure out how to set the object `ObjectRef` when it comes to **Modules** :

```
Public Function CallByName(ByVal ObjectRef As System.Object,ByVal ProcName As String,ByVal UseCallType As CallType, ByVal Args() As Object) As Object
```

Is there a way to do this in VB.Net?

Edit: To make it really simple, I need the equivalent of VBA's:

```
Application.Run module_name.sub_name param
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to create a delegate to the methods in the `Module`.  I would load the created delegates into a `Dictionary(Of String, Action(Of Int32))`.

`Action(Of Int32)` is chosen because it matches the signature you specified of a subroutine taking an integer parameter.

Assume you have a `Module` defined like this:

```
Module SomeModule
    Public Sub Sub1(arg As Int32)
        Console.WriteLine("Sub1: {0}", arg)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Sub2(arg As Int32)
        Console.WriteLine("Sub2: {0}", arg)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now to create and store the delegates in a dictionary.

```
Private methods As New Dictionary(Of String, Action(Of Int32))
Sub LoadMethods()
    Dim modType As Type = GetType(SomeModule)
    Dim mi As Reflection.MethodInfo
    mi = modType.GetMethod("Sub1", BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public)
    methods.Add(mi.Name, CType(mi.CreateDelegate(GetType(Action(Of Int32))), Action(Of Int32)))

    mi = modType.GetMethod("Sub2", BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public)
    methods.Add(mi.Name, CType(mi.CreateDelegate(GetType(Action(Of Int32))), Action(Of Int32)))
End Sub
```

You can retrieve and invoke the delegate like this:

```
methods("Sub1")(123)
methods("Sub2")(456)
```

Edit:  I sometimes makes things to complicated.  The `LoadMethods` method can be done without reflection like this:

```
Sub LoadMethods()
    methods.Add("Sub1", New Action(Of Int32)(AddressOf SomeModule.Sub1))
    methods.Add("Sub2", New Action(Of Int32)(AddressOf SomeModule.Sub1))
End Sub
```

Edit 2: Based on edit to question and comment below.

> Edit: To make it really simple, I need the equivalent of VBA's:
>
> Application.Run module_name.sub_name param

You will need to first extract the `Module` type from its containing assembly based on the entered name.  Then you can retrieve the `MethodInfo` as shown above.  The following example assumes that the module is contained in the executing assembly and has minimal checks implemented.  It will require you to provide the module name, method name and an array properly typed method arguments.  In a real world scenario, it would probably need to take a string of the arguments and perform some type of dynamic type casting to build up the `typedArgs` array based on calling [MethodInfo.GetParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Private Shared Sub Exec(moduleName As String, methodName As String, typedArgs As Object())
    Dim asm As Reflection.Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
    Dim modType As Type = asm.GetType(String.Format("{0}.{1}", asm.GetName.Name, moduleName))
    If modType IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim mi As Reflection.MethodInfo
        mi = modType.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public)
        If mi IsNot Nothing Then
            mi.Invoke(Nothing, typedArgs)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Example usage: `Exec("SomeModule", "Sub1", New Object() {123})`

Comment: Thanks, but this requires that I add every new Sub and every new module to LoadMethods (i dont want maintenance). I want the VB.Net equivalent of VBA: Application.Run module_name.sub_name param

Comment: @BassemLhm,  I provided a basic template for accomplishing your modified requirement as an edit to this answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. Only thing I changed was to replace spaces with underscore in asm.GetName.Name ...

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to call subroutine (or function) **sub1** with parameter **123** with optionally given module name **module1**

Call example, If module name is not available (function name to invoke should be unique among project):

```
Dim FunctionName As String = "sub1"
Dim Param As Integer = 123
InvokeModuleFunction(FunctionNameToCall:=FunctionName, FunctionParameters:=Param)
```

Alternatively, If you know module name:

```
Dim FunctionName As String = "sub1"
Dim Param As Integer = 123    
Dim ModuleName As String = "module1"
InvokeModuleFunction(FunctionNameToCall:=FileType, ModuleName:=ModuleName, FunctionParameters:=Param)
```

InvokeModuleFunction definition

```
Private Sub InvokeModuleFunction(FunctionNameToCall As String, FunctionParameters As Object, Optional ModuleName As String = Nothing)
    Dim MyReflectionAssembly = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    Dim MyFunctionType As Type
    If IsNothing(ModuleName) Then
        'Gets function without ModuleName. FunctionName should be unique in the assembly/programm.
        MyFunctionType = MyReflectionAssembly.DefinedTypes.Where(Function(x) x.DeclaredMethods.Where(Function(y) y.Name = FunctionNameToCall).Count > 0).FirstOrDefault
    Else
        'Gets function using ModuleName, if available
        MyFunctionType = MyReflectionAssembly.DefinedTypes.Where(Function(x) x.Name = ModuleName AndAlso x.DeclaredMethods.Where(Function(y) y.Name = FunctionNameToCall).Count > 0).FirstOrDefault
    End If

    If Not IsNothing(MyFunctionType) Then MyFunctionType.GetMethod(FunctionNameToCall).Invoke(MyFunctionType, New Object() {FunctionParameters})
End Sub
```

Alternatively you can use more than one parameter in invoking.
You would need to modify the above function to allow to pass more than one parameter.
The invoke part would look like:

```
FunctionType.GetMethod(FunctionNameToCall).Invoke(FunctionType, New Object() {Par1, Par2, Par3})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!